# Filtering dataframe based on latest timestamp for each unique id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

Title might be a bit confusing so here's an example:

From:

```
id |     timestamp
 1 | 2015-12-02 00:00:00
 1 | 2015-12-03 00:00:00  <--- latest for id 1
 2 | 2015-12-02 00:00:00
 2 | 2015-12-04 00:00:00
 2 | 2015-12-06 00:00:00  <--- latest for id 2
```

To this:

```
id |     timestamp
 1 | 2015-12-03 00:00:00
 2 | 2015-12-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id').tail(1)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nth`

```
In [599]: df.groupby('id', as_index=False).nth(-1)
Out[599]:
   id            timestamp
1   1  2015-12-03 00:00:00
4   2  2015-12-06 00:00:00
```

Ideally, `max` since you need latest date.

```
In [601]: df.groupby('id', as_index=False).max()
Out[601]:
   id            timestamp
0   1  2015-12-03 00:00:00
1   2  2015-12-06 00:00:00
```

Also, `tail` as mentioned in comments

```
In [602]: df.groupby('id').tail(1)
Out[602]:
   id            timestamp
1   1  2015-12-03 00:00:00
4   2  2015-12-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: max() takes the max on each column, correct?

Comment: From my tests `max` seems to be the only correct option.